# A* heuristic calculation with Euclidean Distance

Tags: java, path-finding, a-star, heuristics

I am implementing A* algorithm in Java for finding the shortest path between two points(the airports in different cities). I am using undirected and weighted graph for this purpose in which each edge represent the distance between two nodes (airports). The Heuristic calculation is done via Euclidean distance. Here is the code of my Heuristic function

```
double Sum = 0;

Sum = Math.pow((destination.getG()-currentNode.getG()),2.0);

return Math.sqrt(Sum);
```

I am calculating the heuristic with G values i,e the edges between nodes. Is it correct? Kindly help. heuristic function take source and destination nodes. I hope its clear.

Comment: That's not how you calculate the euclidean distance.

Comment: Euclidean distance is only appropriate on a plane (plain). For long distance flight you might need to consider that the earth is a kind of a sphere.

Comment: then how should i do this? is there any other heuristic calculation mechanism for finding this? or even if i don't consider the airports as nodes then how is it possible to find the euclidean distance between two nodes? the source and destination.

Comment: An airport usually has coordinates: latitude and longitude (maybe altitude as well). You can use the haversine distance for those kind of measurements.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut yeah i think you are. u mean if i take the long and lat of each node then i can calculate the heuristic without the interference of G in it. is it so?

Comment: The graph just denotes what connections you have between the airports. You only calculate the distance between two adjacent connections in this graph.

Answer (score 9):

You don't use the G score to calculate the heuristic, the G score is added to the heuristic (H score) to get an estimate from the node to the goal (F score).

Euclidean distance is the line illustrated in this image:

[image]

Which, using the two points (x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>) and (x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>) is this:

> h(n) = sqrt((x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> +
>   (y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup>)

Note that you can omit `sqrt()` completely as it's quite a costly operation to perform so many times. Also prefer `float` over `double` as operations on `float`s are much faster.

So try something like this:

```
float x = Math.pow(destination.getX() - currentNode.getX(), 2.0);
float y = Math.pow(destination.getX() - currentNode.getX(), 2.0);

return x + y;
```

I assume you can substitute x and y for long/lat in some fashion (I haven't done much geospatial programming). [This article](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) seems relevant, looks like you need to use the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate the distance.

I wrote an article on A* about a year ago which you may find helpful [here](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/06/a-pathfinding-algorithm.html).

Comment: Thank you so much. This information is truly worthy. :)

Comment: At first I too thought about removing the `sqrt` from the euclidean heuristic, as working with the squared values is a common optimization in computer graphics (especially raymarching). But it seems there are [some who argue for keeping the `sqrt`](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html#euclidean-distance-squared).